# How to switch namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

Say, I have two namespaces k8s-app1 and k8s-app2

I can list all pods from specific namespace using the below command

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace>
```

We need to append namespace to all commands to list objects from the respective namespaces. Is there a way to set specific namespace and list objects without including the namespace explicitly?

Comment: Hi  `kubectl config set-context --help` might be you are looking for

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I was able to switch namespace using the below steps

```
kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=<namespace>
kubectl config view | grep namespace
kubectl get pods
```

This is how i have tested

```
# Create namespaces k8s-app1, k8s-app2 and k8s-app3
master $ kubectl create ns k8s-app1
namespace/k8s-app1 created
master $ kubectl create ns k8s-app2
namespace/k8s-app2 created
master $ kubectl create ns k8s-app3
namespace/k8s-app3 created

# Create Service Account app1-sa in k8s-app1
# Service Account app2-sa in k8s-app2
# Service Account app3-sa in k8s-app3
master $ kubectl create sa app1-sa -n k8s-app1
serviceaccount/app1-sa created
master $ kubectl create sa app2-sa -n k8s-app2
serviceaccount/app2-sa created
master $ kubectl create sa app3-sa -n k8s-app3
serviceaccount/app3-sa created

# Switch namespace
master $ kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=k8s-app1
Context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes" modified.
master $ kubectl config view | grep namespace
    namespace: k8s-app1
master $ kubectl get sa
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
app1-sa   1         1m
default   1         6m
master $
master $ kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=k8s-app2
Context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes" modified.
master $ kubectl get sa
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
app2-sa   1         2m
default   1         7m
master $
master $ kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=k8s-app3
Context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes" modified.
master $ kubectl get sa
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
app3-sa   1         2m
default   1         7m
```

Comment: You may have to use `kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace:` to get current namespace.

Answer (score 469):

I like my answers short, to the point and with references to official documentation:

**Answer**:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=my-namespace
```

**From**:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

```
# permanently save the namespace for all subsequent kubectl commands in that context.
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=ggckad-s2
```

Comment: It's a good practice to validate that the current namespace has changed by executing the following command `kubectl config view | grep namespace:`

Comment: Alternatively, it is possible to just get the namespace without any other tools using `kubectl config view -o jsonpath={.contexts[].context.namespace}`

Answer (score 122):

There are a few options:

- Switch namespace only using the kubectl commands::

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=<namespace>
```

- Or, Create a new context with namespace defined:

```
kubectl config set-context gce-dev --user=cluster-admin --namespace=dev
kubectl config use-context gce-dev
```

- Or, Use addons, like [kubectx & kubens](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx), the below command will switch the context to `kube-system`:

```
$ kubens kube-system
```

- Or, Another easy alternative that I like without installing third party tools, is using bash alias(linux).

```
$ alias kubens='kubectl config set-context --current --namespace '
$ alias kubectx='kubectl config use-context '

// Usage
$ kubens kube-system    //Switch to a different namespace
$ kubectx docker        //Switch to separate context
```

Comment: how do you unset the currrent namespace?

Comment: `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=""`

Answer (score 32):

I didn't like **kubectx** and **kubens** because they are adding one more letter for bash-complection to **kubectl** command.

So I just wrote tiny **kubectl-use** plugin:

```sh
# kubectl use prod
Switched to context "prod".

# kubectl use default
Switched to namespace "default".

# kubectl use stage kube-system
Switched to context "stage".
Switched to namespace "kube-system".
```

If you interesting to it, check https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-use

Comment: This has to be my favorite answer by far! While there is a quite reasonable but unfortunately long command to do this without extending or aliasing kubectl commands, this solution is not only short and sweet to use, but it also - quite nicely - demonstrates how to properly extend kubectl with a simple and understandable subcommand. I tip my hat to you, good Sir! ;-)

Answer (score 29):

You could use the following package called [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) which make it very easy to switch between clusters using **kubectx**

[image]

and switching between namespaces using **kubens**

[image]

Comment: this extension is the best option

Answer (score 7):

I created a function in .zshrc

```
ksns() { kubectl config set-context --current --namespace="$1" }
```

Then I call `ksns default`

Comment: love this command

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/ They have plenty of plugins for different use cases.

For installation
https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/

```
kubectl krew install kubens
```

then after running the following command will set the current context for you

```
kubens <namespace>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace <namespace>` command will set the current namespace.

However, I like to use a little bash function (`kn`) which updates the namespace and also displays all the available namespaces on the Kubernetes cluster:

```bash
function kn () {
  kubectl get ns ; echo 
  if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]; then
    kubectl config set-context --current --namespace $1 ; echo
  fi
  echo "Current namespace [ $(kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace | cut -d " " -f6) ]"
}
```

This can live inside your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile` (Z Shell on Macs) file.

Setting the namespace as follows:

```bash
$ kn postgres

NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   27d
kube-node-lease   Active   27d
kube-public       Active   27d
kube-system       Active   27d
postgres          Active   2d2h

Context "docker-desktop" modified.

Current namespace [ postgres ]
```

> The `Context "docker-desktop" modified.` indicates that the current namespace was updated.

The function also works with no parameters and will display all the namespaces + current namespace.

```bash
$ kn

NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   27d
kube-node-lease   Active   27d
kube-public       Active   27d
kube-system       Active   27d
postgres          Active   2d2h

Current namespace [ postgres ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below short command

`kubectl config set-context --current --namespace={Your_Custom_NameSpace}`

Let us suppose your namespace name is `deepak` , Your command will be as below

`kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=deepak`

Comment: @JeremyCaney I have included the sample command within my explanation. Any specific reason for this comment?

Answer (score 0):

- **kubectx** - for swtiching **contexts/clusters**. Can be installed with "brew install kubectx"
- **kubens**- for switching between **namespaces** in a cluster. Can also be installed with "brew install kubens"

Answer (score 0):

[kubie](https://github.com/sbstp/kubie) can switch context and namespaces.
if you have fzf installed, the experience will be greatly improved.

- `kubie ctx` show the list of available contexts (if fzf is installed, display a selectable menu of contexts)
- `kubie ctx <context>` switch the current shell to the given context (spawns a shell if not a kubie shell)
- `kubie ctx -` switch back to the previous context
- `kubie ctx <context> -r` spawn a recursive shell in the given context
- `kubie ctx <context> -n <namespace>` spawn a shell in the given context and namespace
- `kubie ns` show the list of available namespaces (if fzf is installed, display a selectable menu of namespaces)
- `kubie ns <namespace>` switch the current shell to the given namespace
- `kubie ns -` switch back to the previous namespace
- `kubie ns <namespace> -r` spawn a recursive shell in the given namespace

Answer (score 0):

A `kubectl` replacement maintained by Red Hat for their OCP / OKD  will get this done with less typing (as many other things).

So after downloading `oc Client Tools` from Github ([link](https://github.com/okd-project/okd/releases)), change namespace (yes, in a standard k8s cluster, not just in OKD) by typing:

`oc project <my_ns>`

And to validate:

`oc project`

Note that project and namespace are not fully interchangeable, so in a k8s cluster you cannot list all projects by `oc get projects` (this works only in OKD/OCP), you need this command to list all namespaces:

`oc get ns`

Answer (score -2):

### A Solution

```
npm install -g k8ss

k8ss switch --namespace=your_namespace
kubectl get pods
```

### TLDR; Explanation as requested

There is a npm package called `k8ss` which stands for `K8S Switching between clusters and namespaces`.

The full usage is

```
k8ss switch --cluster=your_new_cluster --namespace=your_new_namespace
```

As in your case, you only need to switch namespace, so you can use the command without any configuration (as you already put a config file in the `~/.kube/config`).

### Advanced Usage

If you need to switch between different clusters then you need to put multiple config files in your home directory. In this case you can go to the [package README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k8ss) to learn more.