# Kubernetes describe pod - Error from server (NotFound)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to debug a pod with the status "ImagePullBackOff".
The pod is in the namespace minio-operator, but when I try to to describe the pod, it is apparently not found.

Why does that happen?

```
[psr-admin@zon-psr-2-u001 ~]$ kubectl get all -n minio-operator
NAME                                  READY    STATUS              RESTARTS    AGE
pod/minio-operator-5dd99dd858-n6fdj   0/1      ImagepullBackoff    0           7d

NAME                             READY.    UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/minio-operator   0         1            0           7d

NAME                                        DESIRED   CURRENT    READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/minio-operator-5dd99dd858   1         1          0         7d
[psr-admin@zon-psr-2-u001 ~]$ kubectl describe pod minio-operator-5dd99dd858-n6fdj
Error from server (NotFound): pods "minio-operator-5dd99dd858-n6fdj" not found
```

`Error from server (NotFound): pods "minio-operator-5dd99dd858-n6fdj" not found`

[image]

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You've not specified the namespace in your describe pod command.

You did `kubectl get all -n minio-operator`, which gets all resources in the `minio-operator` namespace, but your `kubectl describe` has no namespace, so it's looking in the `default` namespace for a pod that isn't there.

```
kubectl describe pod -n minio-operator <pod name>
```

Should work OK.

Most resources in kubernetes are namespaced, so will require the `-n <namespace>` argument unless you [switch namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373686/how-to-switch-namespace-in-kubernetes).

Answer (score -1):

Your correct statement to describe the pods is

```
 kubectl describe pod -n <namespace name>
```

This will list down all the description for all the pods under this namespace