# How to see current namespace with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to Kubernetes and wondering, if there's a `kubectl` command to figure out what namespace I'm currently working in?

Running the `kubectl get ns` command prints out all the namespaces but doesn't show which one I'm in at present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch namespace in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373686/how-to-switch-namespace-in-kubernetes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to inspect the local config for `kubectl` and see current context. This shows your current context with namespace.

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

Example output - can also be multiple clusters, but only one "current":

```
$kubectl config get-contexts   
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE    
*         minikube   minikube   minikube   default
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl config get-contexts`

Should give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much.