# Argocd getting started guide getting FATA[0000] configmap "argocd-cm" not found error

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I just tried to go over the getting started guide of Argocd found here https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/.
I did steps 1 and 2 and then ran the command `argocd login --core` to skip steps 3-5 (as it said in the guide).
when running the next command
`argocd app create guestbook --repo https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git --path guestbook --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default`.
to apply the app itself I got the following error:
`FATA[0000] configmap "argocd-cm" not found`.
Although I did find it on the cluster with the label `app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd`.
I also tried going back to steps 3-5 and changing the server and namespace but some steps didn't work or I didn't know what to do in them, I also got the same error during the second command of step 5.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like the kubectl apply in step one creates that configmap. Do you see any resources in the argocd namespace?

Comment: Yes, the ConfigMap itself exists but for some reason it doesn't register it, In one of the steps you add the clusters context to the Argocd but it didn't help.
I also tried creating the application in the UI but Im still getting an error.

Comment: Note, if you edit a config map via Portainer (v2.16.2) web interface, it may remove the `app.kubernetes.io/part-of` label.

Answer (score 36):

Although the `configmap` is in the `argocd` namespace, if `argocd` is not your *current* namespace, it won't work. To make sure it is, run :

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=argocd
```

That solved it for me. Command from [How to switch namespace in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373686/how-to-switch-namespace-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Now "unable to extract token claims"

Answer (score 7):

As noticed by @emile-tenezakis if it is a *current namespace* issue you can also use the **argocd** `--namespace` or `-n` flag to specify the targeted namespace.

I encountered the same error when running the export command:

```sh
argocd admin export
FATA[0000] configmaps "argocd-cm" not found
```

And I was able to make it work like so:

```sh
argocd -n argocd admin export
```

Comment: You were able to make this work with the `-n` flag? Really? I'm running version 2.5.6 built last week. And it doesn't support this. I get `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -n` and it doesn't show in the help menu. Plus I have noticed this issue which says it doesn't support it. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9123. It is not too recent. But still. I would like to find out how you got this working on your argocd cli. It would be very helpful.

Comment: @ByronMansfield my answer is confusing indeed. The `--namespace` option is not a generic one and its usage depends on the `argocd` sub-command you need to run. For example you can add the `--namespace` option when running sub-commands like `argocd admin export`, `argocd cluster`, `argocd proj`, `argocd repo`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank @martin-tovmassian. That clears it up :)

Answer (score 3):

Is mandatory to set the labels to argocd be able to find the config map:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my `~/.kube` directory was configured with `root:root` permissions; this caused `kubectl` to be unable to switch contexts.

This problem only showed up for me once I manually tried to execute `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=argocd` (it would say: `error: open /home/user/.kube/config.lock: permission denied`).

Once I corrected these permissions the `argocd login` command correctly switched contexts (despite claiming the same earlier) and it was no longer complaining about being unable to find `argocd-cm`.